# Необходимо вывести количество простых чисел

Tags: java

Этот код выводит какие простые числа есть в числе например в числе 11 есть 2 3 5 7 11 но мне нужно вывести количество этих чисел, в числе 11 есть 5 простых чисел

```
    static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {

        if (n <= 1)
            return false;
        
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
    
    static void printPrime(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (isPrime(i))
                System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        printPrime(n);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Модифицируйте функцию printPrime:

```
static void printPrime(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (isPrime(i))
                count++;
        }
        System.out.print(count);
    }
```